# No deep link found if i change intent filter placement

Tags: android, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I have been working on Firebase Dynamic links since yesterday.

This is my main activity:

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(AppInvite.API)
                .build();


        boolean autoLaunchDeepLink = true;
        AppInvite.AppInviteApi.getInvitation(mGoogleApiClient, this, autoLaunchDeepLink)
                .setResultCallback(
                        new ResultCallback<AppInviteInvitationResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(@NonNull AppInviteInvitationResult result) {
                                if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {





                                    try {
                                        deepLink = URLDecoder.decode(deepLink, "UTF-8");
                                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(deepLink);
                                   // String requestId = uri.getQueryParameter("requestID");
                                    String requestId2 = uri.getQueryParameter("extra1");
                                    Log.v("EXTRA PARAMETER  ",requestId2);

                                    if(requestId2 == "value") {
                                        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);

                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                    // ...
                                } else {
                                    Log.d("string  ", "getInvitation: no deep link found.");

                                }
                            }
                        });


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                Uri BASE_URI = Uri.parse("http://example.com/");

                Uri APP_URI = BASE_URI.buildUpon().
                        appendQueryParameter("extra1", "value").build();


                String encodedUri = null;
                try {
                    encodedUri = URLEncoder.encode(APP_URI.toString(), "UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Uri deepLink = Uri.parse("https://eh62u.app.goo.gl/y6N7/?link="+encodedUri);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "GET TICKETS" );
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Click here to get the booked tickets: " + deepLink);

                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}

    }
```

I wanted to start Main2Activity using intent when the deep link was clicked. Android manifest:

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data
                    android:host="example.com"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
            </intent-filter>



        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity">

        </activity>
    </application>
```

Now if I put the deep link intent filter in Main2Activity, when I click the link, it directly opens Main2Activity and doesn't go into Main Activity and OnResult is not called. But now as I have put the intentfilter in main activity, it says no deep link found.

Comment: Main2Activity class has absolutely nothing in it

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is an old version. The new version is more simple with firebase dynamicLink. The documentation can be read in [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive)

In your main activity, perhaps in onCreate put this code :

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
            .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                    // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                    Uri deepLinkUri = null;
                    if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                        deepLinkUri = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                    }
                    if(deepLinkUri != null){
                      // String requestId = deepLinkUri.getQueryParameter("requestID");
                      String requestId2 = deepLinkUri.getQueryParameter("extra1");
                      Log.v("EXTRA PARAMETER  ",requestId2);

                      if(requestId2 == "value") {
                        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);

                        startActivity(intent);
                      }
                      // ...
                    } else {
                       Log.d("string  ", "getDynamicLink: no deep link found.");
                    }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.d("string  ", "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
                }
            });
```

More tutorial can be read in [quickstart here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/invites/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/invites/MainActivity.java)

Comment: I got my code from the Firebase assistant. even though the code is outdated, it should have worked, no?

Comment: what does old version have to do with it?

Comment: Firebase team is putting all their might to make developer's life easier. Why wasting their effort with using old version? Besides if i'm not mistake in order to using google api, we need to enable it in google cloud console, and then create an api key, etc..

Comment: I tried your code. Couldn't resolve FirebaseDynamicLinks. I found I was compiling firebase invite version 10.0.1. But I can't even import  11.4.2 with updated sdk

Comment: ok i did not put maven dependency. So with this new version even GoogleApiClient will not be needed?

Answer (score 0):

You should handle `deeplink` inside the activity's `onNewIntent` as well:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getLayoutId());
    receiveDeeplinkIfHave(); // detect your deeplink here
}
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(final Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        receiveDeeplinkIfHave(); // detect your deeplink here
}
```